# Convert formatted date to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I have an app that displays a tableview of times in the day (oceanic tides). What I want to do is be able to tap on a time and schedule a local notification to fire at that time.

If I print out the date when I tap the cell I get "5/18/2016 03:31 AM". However, if I pass that in as the fireDate object, then the fireDate of the notification is "nil"

If I simply create an NSDate object to fire 15 seconds after tapping the cell, then the fireDate is: "Wednesday, May 18, 2016 at 2:14:11 PM"

So I guess the real question is, how can I convert "5/18/2016 03:31 AM" to "Wednesday, May 18, 2016 at 3:31:00 AM"?

Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't be retrieving the date string from the cell. You should go back to your model. The question is how your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` retrieved/created the string to put in the cell in the first place. Your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` should be going back to that same source. And the answer of how to format it like you asked depends upon how the data was stored in your model. If the model has a `NSDate`, that suggests one approach. If it was a string, that suggests another approach (and begs the question as to what time zone that original string was in).

Comment: You cannot pass "5/18/2016 03:31 AM" as the fireDate property, because the former is a `String` and the latter an `NSDate`. Please show what you are really doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `NSDateFormatter` for formatting the date to the desired output. Here is how you can do that

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle
let dateToFire = formatter.dateFromString(datefromcell) //datefromcell is a string that contains the date you got from tapping the tableview cell
```

For more information on how to format dates, see this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/nsdate/)

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the full style and another command in that link.